# Filtering A Lot Of Words

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to use more than one word in filtering but I couldn't, please help me

```
if target !="1" "2" "3":
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for something like

```
if target not in ['1', '2', '3']:
   pass
```

Answer (score 1):

so lets say for example you got tons of words what you can do is you can put those words in the list and then you can just say **if target is not in the list**

now to cover this in practise i will show you example code written in python

```py
animals = ["cat","mouse","dog","elephant"]
if "dragon" not in animals:
    print("dragon is not in animals")
```

so we assigned the list name to be animals and we put animals that are real now if dragon is not in real animals we want to print "dragon is not in animals" and thats the whole point behind this and i hope it helped you